# How do I use buttons inside of a GridLayout in a ScrollView in Kivy?

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

While designing a GUI using Kivy in Python, I encountered an issue when I place some buttons inside of a GridLayout, and the GridLayout inside of a ScrollView. The issue is that the buttons just don't take inputs anymore. Not sure what to do.

here is an example of what I'm trying to do, however, the button for some reason won't press.

```
.kv
<Exmaple>:
  grid: grid

  ScrollView:
    size_hint: .5, .5
    
    GridLayout:
      id: grid
      
      size_hint_y: None
      height: self.minimum_height
      width: self.minumum_width

      cols: 2
```

```
.py
class Example(FloatLayout):
  grid = ObjectProperty(None)  

  def button_cb(self):
    print('Button has been pressed!')

  def __init__(self):
    super(Example, self).__init__()

    for i in range(5):
      l=Label(text='This is some text: ')
      b=Button(text='Click me!', on_press=button_cb)
  
      self.grid.add_widget(l)
      self.grid.add_widget(b)
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Comment: I figured out the issue, it was by removing the self.mimum_height line in the .kv file! Not sure if this was a bug, but now the buttons work. Sorry for not posting a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: You probably do want the `height: self.minimum_height` in your `GridLayout`. The key is that you must provide heights for the `Labels`, `Buttons`, etc.,  that you add to the `GridLayout`, otherwise the `GridLayout` cannot calculate its minimum height.